# deine Freundin oder deine Freundin?

Tags: word-usage

i'm a female writing to my male friend who is a platonic friend.how should I, at the end of my letter, write:

> "your friend britt"

At the end of his letter he put *Dein Freund Joerg* but I noticed *Freundin* is the same for *friend* (that is a girl) and *girlfriend*.

Comment: wo ist jetzt der Unterschied zw. `deine Freundin ` und `deine Freundin`? Abgesehen davon, dass ich `Deine Freundin` schreiben würde, und davon, dass Freund auch im Sinne von Boyfriend verwendet wird?

Comment: I think "girlfriend" can also mean "female friend", especially among girls.

Answer (score 19):

I think if it's obvious that you're not his girlfriend from the context you can write

> Deine Freundin Brittany

Especially when "Freundin" is used with a name it commonly denominates platonic friendships.

> Tom: "Meine Freundin studiert Geschichte." (girlfriend)
>
> Tom: "Meine Freundin Anja studiert Geschichte." (friend)

Comment: Just to add this: a German would **never** sign a letter to her lover with *"Deine Freundin xxx"*. How we do that would be another nice question here. ;)

Comment: +1 for splattne for the name thing - I've never noticed so far, but it's true. Also, +1 for Takkat - 100% agreed.

Comment: @splattne: Suggestion to add: If it's the girlfriend and her name should be mentioned, the usual form is "Anja, meine Freundin, studiert Geschichte."

Comment: "Meine Freundin Anja" can still mean "my girlfriend Anja", and "meine Freundin" can still mean "my friend" (if he has only 1 female friend or if it's obvious who is referred to) so that's not a rock-solid translation. Even "eine meiner Freundinnen" *can* mean that the author is poly-amorous ;) Only "feste Freundin" or some term of endearment ("mein Schatz Anja") or adjective ("meine liebe Anja") is definite. In other words: It's complicated!

Comment: If I hear "Meine Freundin studiert Geschichte" I'd certainly think "GF".  Just a friend would rather be s.th. like "Eine Freundin von mir studiert Geschichte".  But: "Meine Freundin Anja" is not a bit uncertain.

Comment: But "Meine Freundin, Anja, studiert Geschichte" would mean girlfriend. Of course, you have to hear the commas :)

Answer (score 10):

Note that this is a symmetric situation, "Freund" also denotes "boyfriend".

So, if your German-speaking platonic friend signs his letter like that, you can absolutely mimic that (if you are sure that he also know that you are in a platonic friendship :) ). Letter-endings among friends can be very idiosyncratic, anyway.